# How to use the sforce.one.navigateToList method?

Tags: javascript, salesforce1-app

I see in the Salesforce1 Developer Guide the [section on Managing Navigation](http://docs.developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm) has documentation on the `navigateToList` method.

> ```
> navigateToList(listViewId, listViewName, scope)
> ```
>
> Navigates to the list view as specified by the listViewId and listViewName.

What is the scope parameter?

I have the following Visualforce that should redirect to a list view, assuming that the  `listViewId` is the Id of the list view and the `listViewName` is the Name of the view (i.e., what displays in the picklist in Salesforce web).  I'm not sure what the scope parameter would be, though.

```
<apex:page >
  <script>
      if ( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) {
          sforce.one.navigateToList('00BZ0000000VzdE', 'My Custom List View', ???);
      }
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

I found [this documentation on the Scope Parameter](http://docs.developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/oauth_scope_parameter_values.htm), but it is for oauth, so I assume it wouldn't apply to this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the Entity for your list or more specifically the Entity API name.

- Account
- Contact
- CustObject__c

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!  Worked perfectly with Accounts. I was hoping it would work with Events too, but I guess that's not supported yet: `sforce.one.navigateToList('00BZ0000000VzdE', 'MyEvents', 'Event');`, resulted in an empty list view and an error dialog with 'We couldn't find the record you're trying to access. It may have been deleted by another user, or there may have been a system error. Contact your administrator or salesforce.com for help.'

Comment: Yes it appears as of right now Tasks, Events and Activities cannot be shown in that way.